# Why I can't serialize form with article tags inside?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

When I want serialize my form, return no data and I don't know if my articles inside my form cause this problem.

**Html**

```
<form id="questions">
<article id="uno" class="question">
    <h2>1. Elementos que permiten controlar un ciclo</h2>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="RC1-P1-A" id="answer1_0">
        Bucle y acumulador</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="RC1-P1-B" id="answer1_1">
        Ciclo y contador</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="RC1-P1-C" id="answer1_2">
        Contador y condición</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="RC1-P1-D" id="answer1_3">
        Condición y apuntador</label>
    </p>
</article>
<article id="dos" class="question">
    <h2>2. Elementos que permiten controlar un ciclo</h2>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="RC1-P2-A" id="answer2_0">
        Bucle y acumulador</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="RC1-P2-B" id="answer2_1">
        Ciclo y contador</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="RC1-P2-C" id="answer2_2">
        Contador y condición</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="RC1-P2-D" id="answer2_3">
        Condición y apuntador</label>
    </p>
</article>
<article class="question">
    <input id="sendAnswers" class="btn-send" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    <ul class="error"></ul>
</article>
</form>
```

I have that structure because I have a form slider.

Then, when I do this:

```
console.log($('#questions').serializeArray());
```

or

```
console.log($('#questions').serialize());
```

Don't display data in console.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is none of the radio buttons are selected. It is serializing the form but there are no values to serialize.

Choose an option try the console.log

I added a filled in textbox and preselected on of the radios in the fiddle to demonstrate it working.

```
 $("#sendAnswers").click(function(){ 
   console.log($('#questions').serializeArray());
 });
```

This also works

```
$("#sendAnswers").click(function(){ 
 console.log($('#questions').serialize());
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GcHcW/1/